# How can I select two rows with the same account?

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to do a `select` in one account that has two assets with status X.

I tried with:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' LIMIT 2
```

But this returns two rows with two different accounts... I need it to be the same account...

How does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an aggregate SOQL query for this, and then only return accounts that have more than 1 asset with that status:

```
SELECT AccountId , count(Id) FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' GROUP BY AccountId HAVING Count(AccountId) > 1
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm

Comment: and if I want to get the same account that has 1 asset with status = 'X' and 1 asset with status = 'Y' ?

Comment: @ArthurAlmeida Then you'll need to ask another question (and be prepared to use Apex to do supplemental data processing).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like 1 or 2:

1.

```sql
SELECT AccountId FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'X' GROUP BY AccountId
```

2. 

```sql
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Assets WHERE Status = 'X') FROM Account
```

Comment: Of these two, #2 is the closest, I think, but this doesn't quite satisfy the request. I think that Guy's answer which uses both `GROUP BY` and, crucially, `HAVING` is the approach. Otherwise, you'll need to process the results in Apex to get "AccountIds with 2 or more Assets with a Status of "X" "